# Encountering an Issue Fetching API Data using "option" in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've been diving into Next.js 13 and I'm having some trouble fetching data from an API within my application. Despite my efforts, I keep encountering an error whenever I attempt to make API calls.

To provide a bit more context, I'm working on a project where I'm using the latest version of Next.js (v13). My goal is to fetch data from an external API and display it in my application. I've double-checked my code and the API documentation, but I'm still getting stuck.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const API_KEY = process.env.ACCOMMODATION_API_KEY;
const apiUrlBase = "https://hotels4.p.rapidapi.com/locations/v2/search";
const headers = {
  "x-rapidapi-host": "hotels4.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": API_KEY,
};

export async function GET(req) {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: apiUrlBase,
      params: {
        query: req.query.searchCity,
        locale: "en_US",
        currency: "USD",
      },
      headers: headers,
    };

    const response = await fetch(options.url, {
      method: options.method,
      headers: options.headers,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Request to API failed");
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return NextResponse.json(responseData);
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Error while fetching accommodation data.",
        error: error.message,
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

Frontend code:

```
  const getCity = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("api/city/", {
        params: { searchCity },
      });
      const { data } = res;
      setCity(data.suggestions[0].entities[0].destinationId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Error I'm facing when trying to access the route `http://localhost:3000/api/city`:

Error Message `{"message":"Error while fetching accommodation data.","error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchCity')"}`

Comment: `params: { searchCity },` - you did not give the value you are sending there any parameter name - this should be `params: { searchCity: searchCity }`